# Issue using observable collection and a listbox - Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am having trouble using Observablecollection and a listbox with a item template.

The issue is, that it doesn't seem to add it to the listbox when i add it to the observable collection. Issue may be the data context? Still learning C#, so it may be a newb error, thanks for the help.

Mainwindow:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = ?

            Reminders.Add(new Remind(new DateTime(), "Hello"));
            Reminders.Add(new Remind(new DateTime(), "asd"));
            Reminders.Add(new Remind(new DateTime(), "gfs"));
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Remind> Reminders = new ObservableCollection<Remind>();

        public ObservableCollection<Remind> reminders
        {
            get
            {
                return Reminders;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mainwindow Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Reminder.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Reminder" Height="357" Width="372">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,2,2">
        <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="507">
            <MenuItem Header = "File" Width="32">
                <MenuItem Header="New Reminder"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Delete Reminder"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Change"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Options">

            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="About">
                <MenuItem Header="Info"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <Button  Content="New" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="6,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" />
        <Button Content ="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="87,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" />
        <Button Content="Change" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="166,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73" />
        <ScrollViewer Name="Scroller" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="235" Margin="0,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="346">
            <ListBox ItemsSource= "{Binding reminders}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Height="41" Width="293" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=dateT}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Msg}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="13" Margin="0,266,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="362"/>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Reminders Code:

```
namespace Reminder
{
    public class Remind : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        public Remind(DateTime dt, string ms)
        {
            dateT = dt;
            Msg = ms;
        }

        private DateTime datet;

        public DateTime dateT
        {
            get
            {
                return datet;
            }

            set
            {
                if (datet != value)
                {
                    datet = value;
                    RaisePropertyChange("dateT");
                }
            }
        }

        private string msg;

        public string Msg
        {
            get
            {
                return msg;
            }
            set
            {
                if (msg != value)
                {
                    msg = value;
                    RaisePropertyChange("Msg");
                }
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChange(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `DataContext` to itself:

```
DataContext = this;
```

OR

You can set in XAML as well:

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

---

On a side note **properties name should be in Pascal Case and private backup fields should have camel casing**. So, as per convention it should be:

```
private ObservableCollection<Remind> reminders =
                     new ObservableCollection<Remind>();

public ObservableCollection<Remind> Reminders
{
   get
   {
      return reminders;
   }
}
```

and need to update binding in XAML as well:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource= "{Binding Reminders}">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do the two perform exactly the same? Thanks for correcting it, fixed it up.

Comment: Yeah you can set it either way.